# Vb.Net - Using multi-dimensional array

Tags: vb.net

Can some please help- Previously I was storing this in database

```
File Name - Order.csv 
File Arrival Time - 03:00
File Arrival End time - 04:00
```

But now I need to move this out from database and using MULTI-DIMENSIONAL ARRAY to store values and then iterate through them to check if files has arrived.

I have the code to check for file existance but im new to vb.net so don't now how to store this in multi-dimensional array and then iterate through it.

Please help.

Comment: may you plz give alittle more insight into the problem e.g the current code u are using,how many fields you are expecting from the DB because Rex 's answer looks pretty ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you really want to use arrays, you could try something like:

```
Dim data(,,) As String
ReDim data(10, 10, 10) ' three dimensions
For i As Integer = 0 To data.GetUpperBound(0)
    For j As Integer = 0 To data.GetUpperBound(1)
        For k As Integer = 0 To data.GetUpperBound(2)
           ' do your stuff here
        Next
    Next
Next
```

But, why not use object and list instead? something like:

```
Public Class MyFile
    Property Name As String
    Property ArrivalTime As DateTime
    Property EndTime As DateTime
End Class

' then store the data in a list(of MyFile):
Public Class Test
    Sub LoadingData()
        Dim myData = New List(Of MyFile)
        Using conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("your connection string here")
            Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
                cmd.Connection = conn
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT top 100 Name, ArrivalTime, EndTime FROM yourTable"
                conn.Open()
                Using rdr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
                    Dim namePos = rdr.GetOrdinal("Name")
                    Dim timePos = rdr.GetOrdinal("Time")
                    Dim endTimePos = rdr.GetOrdinal("EndTime")
                    While rdr.Read()
                        myData.Add(New MyFile With {.Name = rdr.GetString(namePos),
                                                   .ArrivalTime = rdr.GetDateTime(timePos),
                                                   .EndTime = rdr.GetDateTime(endTimePos)})
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        For Each item In myData
            ' Do whatever you like with each item
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Name: {0}, Arrival Time: {1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}, End Time: {2:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}",
                                            item.Name,
                                            item.ArrivalTime,
                                            item.EndTime))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

-- just a quick sample, not tested, you may tweak according to your needs)...

Comment: I need to add code in SSIS Package - Script component using Vb.Net. As im new can you please suggest you mention code in FOR each LOOP also please...